# What is the recursive relation for three-particle Green's functions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams, many-body, greens-functions

In condensed matter physics, one often choose to study the many-body Green's functions (GF) with the diagram (perturbation) expansion technique. In what follows only two-body interaction is concerned.

The one-particle GF satisfies a recursive equation also known as the Dyson equation, where the irreducible kernel is the so-called self-energy $\Sigma$. To approach $\Sigma$ one often selects a certain set of skeleton diagrams which are generated from differentiating some Luttinger-Ward diagrams: $\Sigma  = \delta \Phi /\delta G$.

Differentiating $\Phi$ twice one obtains the two-particle irreducible kernel $K= \delta \Sigma  /\delta G$, which has four legs (indices). $K$ is the kernel of the recursive equation (Bethe-Salpeter) for two-particle GF's.

My question: Is there any recursive equation for 3-particle GF? (I've seen something called Faddeev equation in a nuclear physics literature. Can anyone provide some details, preferably in the context of condensed matter?) And does $\delta K/\delta G$ mean any kernel thing in that equation? If yes, how does it work? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer to this question in the meantime?

Comment: http://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.11.257